# library header for finding 2 minimum value from array in java

Tags: java

I know how to get 2 minimum values from an array manually. But I don't know whether any function exists in some library.

Does anyone know if a function exists in a library that would find the 2 minimum values?

Comment: It sounds like you already made a library for this. Anyway, sort the array and take the two first elements?

Comment: there is library exits like getminimum(array[]); gives only 1 value. but wt abt 2 or 3 or four etc??

Comment: You can probably do it with streams and an anon function pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] inputArray = { 5, 3, 2, 4, 1, 0 };
    Arrays.sort(inputArray);
    System.out.println("First: " + getMinimum(inputArray, 0) + " Second: " + getMinimum(inputArray, 1));

}

public static int getMinimum(int[] inputArray, int position){
    return arr[position];
}
```

Comment: The OP has a solution already. Besides, why sort if you can solve this problem in linear time?